# key exchange algorithm with optional parties

Tags: java, security, cryptography, pgp, diffie-hellman

I need to generate a secret key (or password) with agreement of multiple parties out of which some parties are optional.

For example, Mr. A, B, C & D are members who can do agreement and out of which atleast two agreements are required to generate the secret. However the secret should be same for all such key agreements.

I went through Diffie-Hellman algorithm but it requires all keys. Essentially what i am looking at is 1 private key and n public key type of key exchange algorithm.

Please suggest some algorithms to have this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Public Key cryptosystems I know of uses a 1-1 key relationship. So it's not possible with the standard algorithms available.

What you are looking for is a [Threshold Cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_cryptosystem) or something like [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).

Comment: Thank you, Sani! Good pointers for me.